# Raspberry PI connect with Analog Devices ADIS16227

Tags: gpio

I want to measure the fan vibration signal by Raspberry PI + ADIS 16227 (+/-70g). However, I can't search any reference in Google. Does anybody know how to do the the wiring of the two items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to use the SPI interface.

You need to connect it to the Pi's SPI gpios.

See http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals for the layout of pins on P1.

The datasheet show these connections.

```
Pin No.  Mnemonic Type Description
1,4,9,10 GND      S    Ground
2, 6     NC       I    No Connect
3        DIO2     I/O  Digital Input/Output Line 2
5        DIO1     I/O  Digital Input/Output Line 1
7        RST      I    Reset, Active Low
8        VDD      S    Power Supply, 3.3 V
11       DIN      I    SPI, Data Input
12       DOUT     O    SPI, Data Output
13       SCLK     I    SPI, Serial Clock
14       CS       I    SPI, Chip Select
```

Then use the SPI device to transfer bytes to and from the ADIS16227.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth checking out [WebIOPi](https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/). This [supports many devices](https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/wiki/DEVICES), although unfortunately I do not see yours on there. However you could request they write a driver or fork their repo and use it as a place to start.

> **Device not listed ?**
>
> I cannot write a driver for all components, mainly because I don't have them, and I cannot buy everything. I could write drivers simply reading specs, but I will not be able to certify it work.
>
> **Submit your devices**
>
> Feel free to submit any component you use and/or would like to use with WebIOPi on the bug tracker. Depending on demands, I may write the driver if I can have a sample.
>
> **How to help**
>
> If you know how the device work on it's low level interface, look on the source repository, starting with PCF8574, write your own and submit it. You can also provide me a sample so I can write the driver.